# Yii2 динамическая валидация

Tags: javascript, yii2

У меня есть два филда. Нужно, что бы второй филд валидировался на клиент-сайде в зависимости от выбора первого.
Мне нужно динамически менять yii.validation.required(value, messages) для другого филда при выборе первого, но возможно ли это вообще? По стандарту yii.validation.required(value, messages) работает только для текущего филда(т.е. то, с которым сейчас происходит действие). Буду благодарен, если подскажете еще какой-нибудь способ, которым я могу динамически менять валидацию второго поля в зависимости от первого...

@Blacknife
Я бы хотел сделать что-то вроде

```
[['hours', 'minutes'], 'required', 'whenClient' => 'function (attribute, value) {
           if($('#customer-hours').val() == 0 && $('#customer-minutes').val() == 0){
//если hours == 0 и minutes == 0, то нужно как-то передать ошибку об обязательном заполнении в minutes из hours, а в hours оставить по дефолту как есть required
}
}', 'message' => 'Обязательно к заполнению']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Для несложной валидации на стороне клиента используйте [whenClient](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$whenClient-detail).**

Допустим, первое поле `type` - это тип объекта `[1 => 'тип1', 2 => 'тип2']` + допустим, что это `select`, а второе поле `description` обязательно к заполнению только при условии, что выбран `тип2`:

```
['description', 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
    return $model->type == 2;
}, 'whenClient' => 'function (attribute, value) {
    return $("select option:selected").val() === 2;
}', 'message' => 'Описание обязательно к заполнению']
```

Этот код описывает и серверную и клиентскую валидацию, и говорит: *поле "описание" обязательно к заполнению, если выбран тип 2*

Есть ещё более тонкий метод [clientValidateAttribute](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#clientValidateAttribute()-detail), для него необходимо создать собственный класс валидатора, но исходя из вопроса не могу сказать, что именно Вам нужно.

**Исходя из поправок в вопросе:**

```
[['hours', 'minutes'], 'required'],
['hours', 'integer', 'min' => 0, 'max' => 23],
['minutes', 'integer', 'min' => 0, 'max' => 59],
['minutes', 'compare', 'compareValue' => 0, 'operator' => '>', 'when' => function ($model) {
    return $model->hours == 0;
}, 'whenClient' => 'function (attribute, value) {
       return $('#customer-hours').val() == 0;
}', 'message' => 'minutes не может быть 0 в данном случае']
```

Comment: Отписал Вам в основном посте.

Comment: @RSalnikov постарайтесь описать более понятно вот это `если hours == 0 и minutes == 0, то нужно как-то передать ошибку об обязательном заполнении в minutes из hours, а в hours оставить по дефолту как есть required`

Comment: есть какое-то условие, где при значениях hours = 0 и minutes = 0 показывать реквайр ошибку для значения minutes, что оно не может быть 0 в данной ситуации(в остальных случаях эти два поля будут просто реквайр как есть). проблема в том, что если у нас например есть hours = 12 и minutes = 0 и мы делаем hours = 0, то нужно как-то сказать валидатору на клиент-сайде, что minutes не может быть 0 в данном случае. в этом вся проблема

Comment: @RSalnikov то-есть `minutes` не должно равняться `0` если `hours = 0`?

Comment: т.е. если minutes равняется 0 и при этом же hours = 0, то показывать ошибку валидатора, что minutes не может быть 0 в данном случае

Comment: @RSalnikov вы поправляете или я правильно понял всё-таки?

Comment: я чуть-чуть поправляю=) а, забыл дописать, что ошибку нужно показывать конкретно под полем minutes

Comment: @RSalnikov вы очень сложно формулируете вопрос, ведь действительно то что вам нужно можно сказать так `minutes не должно равняться 0 если hours = 0`. добавил в ответ нужное вам правило

Comment: Спасибо, что натолкнули на решение задачи=)

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря помощи @Blacknife решил задачу на клиент-сайде следующим образом

```
    ['hours', 'required', 'whenClient' => "function(attribute){
            $(attribute.input).closest('form').yiiActiveForm('validateAttribute', 'customer-minutes');
    }"],

    ['minutes', 'compare', 'compareValue' => 0, 'operator' => '!=', 'when' => function ($model) {
        return $model->hours == 0;
    }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
        return $('#customer-hours').val() == 0;
    }",]
```